# How to keep track of next item in dict (Recursive loop)

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I tried, with `enumeration()` and `i` var to keep track of the recursive function, unfortunately, the values are misleading. I am wondering, is there a way to know when the loop is done with the first item and has entered the next item. Note, I am trying this on a nested dict. Thanks in advance.

```
def recursive_loop_dict(d = None): 
    for k,v in d.items(): 
        if isinstance(v, (dict, OrderedDict)): 
            recursive_loop(v) 
         else: 
            print(k, v)
```

**Once looped, and processed the first item, how do I know, that it's moved to the second, 00002 given the fact that this is recursive?**

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "000001" : {
        "title": "Microsoft", 
        "website": "http://www.microsoft.com", 
        "extra": {
            "tags": "MS, Microsoft, Bill Gates"
        }   
    }, 
    "000002" : {
        "title": "YouTube", 
        "website": "http://www.youtube.com", 
        "extra": {
            "tags": "tube, video, stream"
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code doesn't do what you expect, it probably also won't do what you expect, when we run it. But you don't say what you *do* expect. So you are asking us to read broken code, work out what it would do if it were not broken, and suggest how to fix it. That is a bit of a tall order.

Comment: Note that `OrderedDict` inherits from `dict` so `isinstance(v, dict)` alone is sufficient.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: I KNOW!

Comment: Okay easy tiger, no need to shout :)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, YEAH! "geasy tiger", I solve it myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**My solution:**

```
for n in items: 
   # Do something ...
else: 
   # The magic goes here ...
```

Hope this helps other people!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below. Pass the iteration as param inside the method call. Verify the call iteration variable.

```
def recursive_loop_dict(d = None, it = 0): 
    if it == 1:
        print('This is second iteration')
    for i, (k,v) in enumerate(d.items()): 
        if isinstance(v, (dict, OrderedDict)): 
            recursive_loop(v, i) 
        else: 
            print(k, v)
```

Comment: Something, I thought of. But decided to get feedback here. I will do some test on my side. The thing is, I cannot keep track if only second. I want to know, every time it changes, remember: recursive functions can give you misleading results.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method will be using a list as default arg:

```
def recursive_loop_dict(d = None,i=[],start=True):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if start:
            i.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            recursive_loop_dict(v,start=False)
        else:
            print(len(i), k, v)
```

Comment: This gives how nested the current level is. With your sample provided, I have updated the answer.

Comment: The problem, is that it doesn't let me have absolute control.